# gevent create_connection seems to take five-seconds, every time

Tags: sockets, gevent

I'm connecting to a third-party server whose official client connects immediately. However, my client takes five-seconds every time.

The create_connection() call takes a timeout, and, if omitted, it uses the value from gevent.socket.getdefaulttimeout(). On my system, this is "None". Even if I explicitly set the timeout to "1" (whether this represents seconds, milliseconds, microseconds, etc...), it takes the same amount of time, consistently.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same issue. I connect to localhost. my second greenlet (main loop) sleeps 30 times per second. about 5 seconds after the connection is printed in the server log, and after 5 more seconds i get the server response message.